# Formatting lines of code to be a certain length in Jetbrain's IdeaIde

Tags: intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide

I like having my monitor in the vertical portrait position as it makes it easier to read long files. The only problem is that I have to scroll horizontally whenever I have a long line. Is there a setting or plugin that will elegantly format the lines of code so they return at a specified length in Jetbrain's Idea?

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple options, soft wrap or change the right margin.

Soft wrap of course don't alter the code, but removes any horizontal scrolling. The possible issue is that it wraps right against the left edge, breaking any clean formatting that may be present.
This can be enabled under *Settings > Editor > General - "Use soft wraps in editor"*
Also available for the console under *Settings > Editor > General > Console - "Use soft wraps in console"*

Changing the right margin will alter the code, as it is part of the formatting options. There is more control over how the now wrapped code will be formatted though, under the Code Style sub-options.
This can be enabled under *Settings > Editor > Code Style -* change the *"Right margin (columns)"* input to the desired width. Optionally, select the *"Wrap on typing"* option, which will automatically format long lines as you type them.